# When I step on gas pedal, the engine revs up but there is no acceleration

Tags: acceleration

When I step on gas pedal, the engine revs up but there is no acceleration. When step off gas a bit it car starts to accelerate again. It's a manual transmission. 2005 Toyota Corolla. This is happening more and more frequently.

Is this a problem with the transmission, clutch or something else altogether? And wondering if it's going to cost a lot to fix.

Comment: How long have you owned it? How many miles are on it? How many miles did the term of your ownership put on it?

Comment: I'm the original owner so 13 years with approx 275000km

Comment: Wow, very nice. Definitely sounds like a clutch problem so if you get it repaired then enjoy your car for the next 275000km!

Comment: Yes! If it wasn't for the rust I think it would be best to fix but these canadian winters are not so kind...i'm not sure I'd get another 275000km  :)

Comment: I personally wouldn't agree that you should go for a factory dual mass unit if/when you replace the flywheel, my suggestion is to get a 'stock pressure' organic aftermarket clutch kit from someone like ACT or Exceddy, with a single mass flywheel. MUCH cheaper option than an OEM replacement, and honestly it's just NVH (noise/vibration/harshness) that a dual mass flywheel helps with in a car like yours.

Comment: @AaronLavers Vibration and "harshness" accelerate long term cumulative damage - if you have two identical cars and one has vibration problems then I guarantee you all types of things will fail sooner on that car than the other.  Cars with DMFs are usually designed to expect them - the synchros, carrier bearings, etc, are all typically lighter in cars with DMFs because they expect the DMF to absorb a lot of the shock and vibration.  I'm not sure about Corollas, but it's not generally true that you can safely swap a DMF for SMF.

Comment: @J... to be honest, I've pulled the dual mass flys out of more than a handful of cars that are still chugging along years afterwards. I don't disagree that harmonics from NVH can cause issues over time, but my in my experience switching from a dual mass to a single mass hasn't caused any damage at all. Just changes the way the car drives (i.e. less flywheel mass changing how the car drives in traffic, which just comes down to driver preferences).

Answer (score 20):

This sounds like the classic symptoms of a slipping clutch.

The solution is to replace it or have it replaced. If it is a DMF (Dual Mass Flywheel - fitted to reduce vibration) type then it is usually a good idea to replace that as well at the same time.

The minimum will be a centre or friction plate, but personally I will always fit a new pressure plate at the same time. If the flywheel surface shows serious signs of wear then that may need skimming or replacing.

As for prices, they vary between countries, and within countries even, for the cost of labor, parts also vary in price, so you have to find out for your area.

Comment: @AsenM well, I know people who are selling who do the minimum... but others who are keeping do do the dmf at the same time...

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll have to get an estimate on the repair...figure out if it's worth the repair cost. It's getting up there in age  :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

While I agree it is probably a slipping clutch, before I had the cluth and pressure plate replaced I think you would want to have the clutch pedal cable checked to see if it is mis-adjusted. In some cases the pedal play may be causing the clutch to be slightly engaged even when your foot is off the pedal. This adjustment should be very inexpensive if you haven't already polished (hence damaged) the friction plate.
The sooner the better to avoid further damage.

Comment: While modern cars can have their clutch engagement point adjusted, it should be noted that an '05 Corolla uses a hydraulic clutch system and not a cable system. Of course, Rob's not wrong here - a misadjusted clutch (or even one that needs new fluid or a good bleed) can cause this symptom.

Comment: On a car with 275,000km on the original clutch... I mean, odds are

Comment: Sure, but $50 to have a mechanic check the cable before you spend 10x+ on parts and labor for a clutch isn't absurd.

Comment: @Adonalsium it is difficult to check a clutch cable for correct functioning on a car with a hydraulic clutch - asking a mechanic to do that will confirm his opinion of some customers...